# Pass Ionic2 popover ngModel value to and call function in parent Page component?

Tags: typescript, angular, popover, ionic2, angular2-ngmodel

Here's what I am trying to do.

- Putting group radio buttons in the Ionic2 popover menu.
- The options are actually controling which JSON file the content is
  going to load.
- User select an option, close the popover, content will update
  accordingly in the page.

I am not sure how to pass value from a Ionic2 Popover to it's parent component. If I understand it correctly Ionic2's Popover is a child component. However I dont know how to pass the `[(ngModel)]` value out.

I know it looks messy here... well if only someones kind enough to make a simple example of how to pass value from PopOver to the Page...

So... this all in one file:

```
import {Component, Injectable, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewController, NavController, Popover, Content, Events, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {CardService} from '../../providers/card-service/card-service';
import {LangService} from '../../providers/lang-service/lang-service';
import {GlobalService} from '../../providers/global-service';
```

The Popover component:

```
@Component({template: `
    <ion-list  radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected"  (ionChange)="loadc(selected)"> 

        <ion-item  *ngFor="let chapter of menuArray">
            <ion-label>{{chapter.ctitle}}</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="{{chapter.cchap}}" ></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

        `,
    providers: [CardService, LangService, GlobalService],
directives: [LangService]
})

@Injectable()
export class ChapterService{
private chpselected : any;
private menuArray: any;
    constructor(
    private viewCtrl: ViewController,
    private navController: NavController,
    public cardService: CardService,
    public langService: LangService,
    public globalService: GlobalService

    ) {
        this.menuArray = [
    {
                id: 0,
                cchap: '01',
                ctitle: 'One',
        },
    {
                id: 1,
                cchap: '02',
                ctitle: 'Two',
        },
    {
                id: 2,
                cchap: '03',
                ctitle: 'Three',
        },
];
        ///
 this.chpselected = this.menuArray[0]; 

        ///
    };

  close() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

///-------------------------------
   Here I triggers an even when clicking the radio buttons in the popover. I want to call the loadCards() function in the HomePage class below so it returns what is selected and load the correct JSON in the DOM. However I do not how to pass this loadc() value to loadCards().
///-------------------------------

    loadc(x){
    console.log(x);
        this.globalService.nowchap = x;
    };


};
```

Another Class here, the Page:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
    providers: [CardService, LangService, ChapterService, HomePage, GlobalService],
directives: [LangService]
})

@Injectable()
export class HomePage {
///  
public cards;
public viewmode : any;
    constructor(
    private navController: NavController,
    public cardService: CardService,
    public langService: LangService,
    public globalService: GlobalService
    //public chapterService: ChapterService
    ){



    this.viewmode ="read";
        this.loadCards();
    };

    /* POPOVER*/
    presentPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = Popover.create(ChapterService);
    this.navController.present(popover, {
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }

/* Contents are loading here */
  public loadCards(x){
    console.log("this chp is "+x);
    this.cardService.load(x)
    .then(data => {
      this.cards = data;
    });

  }

/* LOAD CARDS ENDED*/    
///
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for Service, it just complicates things..

See complete plunkr here - https://plnkr.co/edit/s6lT1a?p=info

it the caller, pass a callback...

```
 presentPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = Popover.create(PopoverComponent,{
      cb: function(_data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(_data))
      }
    });

    this.nav.present(popover, {
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }
```

in the popover...

```
constructor(private params: NavParams. /* removed rest for purpose of demo */ ) {
   this.callback = this.params.get('cb')
}

public loadc(x) {

   this.callback(x)

  // Close the popover
  this.close();
}
```

Comment: updated plunker to show how to solve the problem using the onDismiss callback also

Comment: The call back data appears in the alert but not in the parent page for me in your plnkr.

Comment: Hi @Aron , Please tell me how to highlight the selected item the popover

Answer (score 1):

> Here's what I am trying to do.
>
> Putting group radio buttons in the Ionic2 popover menu.
>
> The options are actually controling which JSON file the content is going to load.
>
> User select an option, close the popover, content will update accordingly in the page.

You can easily achive that by using a **shared service** to handle the communication between your popover page and your `HomePage`. Please take a look at [this workin plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TPXCHx?p=preview).

I've seen you're using a `globalService` so I propose a small change to make it work like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular/index';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService { 

  // Your properties...

  public getChapterObserver: any;
  public getChapter: any;

  constructor(...){
    // Your code...

    // I'm adding an observer so the HomePage can subscribe to it
    this.getChapterObserver = null;
    this.getChapter = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.getChapterObserver = observer;
    });

  }

  // Method executed when selecting a radio from the popover
  public selectChapter(chapter : any) {
    this.getChapterObserver.next(chapter);
  }

}
```

Then, in your `PopoverPage`:

```
public loadc(x) {
    // You can call your globalService like this
    //this.globalService.selectChapter(this.menuArray[this.selected]);  

    // O by simply doing
    this.globalService.selectChapter(x);

    // Close the popover
    this.close();
}
```

So now we're telling our service that the `selectChapter` has changed. And finally, in your `HomePage`:

```
constructor(private nav: NavController, private globalService: GlobalService) {

  // We subscribe to the selectChapter event
  this.globalService.getChapter.subscribe((selectedChapter) => {
      this.selectedChapter = selectedChapter;
    });
}
```

With that, we're subscribing the `HomePage` to that `GlobalService`, so when the chapter changes, we're going to be noticed and we can handle that as we want.